# Why does this not match?

Tags: c++

Why does this not match ?

```
...
puts (ep->d_name);
if(ep->d_name=="testme"){ printf("ok"); } else { printf("no"); }
...
```

output:

```
testme
no
```

Comment: Considering he can pass it directly to `puts`, I'm guessing it's not `string`.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin: Touche, but it could be overloaded. (unlikely, I know)

Comment: d_name is an array of 256 chars ( http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir )

Comment: @PaulR: Bad C++, but still C++.

Comment: Why the downvotes on the question? Looks valid for me. Maybe misses the variable type but still.

Comment: Unless `ep->d_name` is also pointing to a constant, they're not equivalent pointers.

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
if(!strcmp(ep->d_name, "testme"))
```

or make `d_name` a `string` instead.

Answer (score 6):

This is happening because you are comparing to two pointers, which point to the char* with the same value

you should really do

```
puts (ep->d_name);
if(strcmp(ep->d_name, "testme")==0){ 
    printf("ok"); 
}
else { 
    printf("no"); 
}
```

Although please consider using string as that will give you the semantics you require

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string

Answer (score 1):

We need to know what value is being passed with d_name.

For the program to print "ok", the value needs to be "testme" as well.

Also, check out this function: strcmp.  It compares two strings, which essentially is what you are doing here.

Example:

```
    /* strcmp example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char szKey[] = "apple";
  char szInput[80];
  do {
     printf ("Guess my favourite fruit? ");
     gets (szInput);
  } while (strcmp (szKey,szInput) != 0);
  puts ("Correct answer!");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The posters code shows that `d_name` is `"testme"` due to the `puts` output. The only error is that he's not using `strcmp`.

Comment: Oh I see that now. Thanks Pubby.